# Can a sacred cow transmit shaktipat?

Tags: yoga, cows

Can a sacred cow transmit shaktipat or only humans can do it?
If so, another animals can do it?

Comment: can you please explain what is a shaktipat?

Comment: @juztcode https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shaktipat

Comment: @Leandros López , but what does a cow have to do with Kundalini and hence shaktipat?

Comment: @juztcode I don't know very well, that's why I'm asking. The Cow is a sacred animal to Hindus. A cow, sure enough, has her own Kundalini energy, and I found no answer elsewhere... Nandi, is Shiva's Dvarapalaka, being a bull and guru at the same time, so, being a guru, he can trasmit shaktipat. So, a Hinduism expert or religious may be in grade to answer this question in a foundamented way.

Comment: As far as I know only Guru can do Shaktipat. Can you tell where you read about cow doing Shaktipat?@LeandrosLópez

Comment: @Rickross, read my comment above, when I answered to the user juztcode. It's already there the motives of my question.